# Error while trying to define a function to create price bucket for apps

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-loc

I have an csv data set that I imported in Jupyter and stored under inp0.
I'm trying to create price bucket for these using .loc function in pandas bet getting below error.

My Code:

```
inp0.loc[inp0.price==0.00, 'Price_Bucket'] = 'Free App'
inp0.loc[[inp0.price>0.00 and inp0.price<3.00],'Price_Bucket'] = 'Apps that cost <3'
inp0.loc[[inp0.price>=3.00 and inp0.price<5.00],'Price_Bucket'] = 'Apps that cost <5'
inp0.loc[inp0.price>=5.00,'Price_Bucket'] = 'Apps that cost >=5'
inp0.price_bucket.value_counts()
```

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Instead of boolean `and` use bitwise `&`

Comment: `[inp0.price>0.00 and inp0.price<3.00]` should be `(inp0.price>0.00) & (inp0.price<3.00)`.  you are doing a bitwise and of two numpy boolean arrays

Comment: When I use "&" instead of "and" I get multiple errors. Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]. ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with np.where which works like if else in columns/vectors:

```
import numpy as np
inp0['Price_Bucket'] = np.where(inp0['price']==0.00, 'Free App', np.where(inp0['price']<3.00, 'Apps that cost <3', np.where(inp0['price']<5.00, 'Apps that cost <5', 'Apps that cost >=5')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing multiple `ifelse` or `np.where` condition you can use pandas `cut` function like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

bins_defined = [0, 0.000001, 3, 5, math.inf] ## price = 0 --> 'Free APP' that's why i've selected the first two interval in a tricky way
labels_defined = ['Free App', 'Apps that cost <3', 'Apps that cost <5', 'Apps that cost >=5']

inp0['Price_Bucket'] = pd.cut(inp0['price'], bins = bins_defined, labels = label_defined, right = False)

#  `right` Indicates whether bins includes the rightmost edge or not. 
# If right == True (the default), then the bins [1, 2, 3, 4] indicate (1,2], (2,3], (3,4].
```

For better understandinfg see the pandas.cut documentation